# Should I use a query parameter or separate endpoints for different data access levels?

Tags: rest, api-design

I have an API endpoint for retrieving articles:

```
GET /articles
```

This endpoint can be accessed by both guests and administrators. The distinction lies in the data that can be retrieved.

For example, anyone can access this endpoint to show articles (by default it only show published articles):

```
GET /articles
```

However, if a query parameter is added:

```
GET /articles?withUnpublished
```

In this case, the client is required to provide an authentication token with the `articles:read_unpublished` scope.

Is this strategy ideal, or would it still be advisable to separate the endpoints? The response format remains the same, the only difference is in the accessible data.

I would like to know the community's opinion on whether this approach is suitable for my API design.

Comment: While there is nothing inherently wrong with making it into a single endpoint, I think you'll find that verifying access rights based on the value of a query param is not a common scenario, and consequently, there is no likely no declarative support in your BE framework . You will end up with verifying access rights imperatively, or creating a highly nonstandard security idiom. Either way makes the code harder to reason about, which for me would be a valid reason to avoid taking this path if at all possible.

Comment: Yeah, seeing the Open API definition usually they put certain security schemes for each endpoint, not conditionally inside one endpoint. But for same use case, same request body, and same response body structure, i don't think that we should separate the endpoint further. But yeah, kinda weird when seeing inside the documentation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not split this URL into two or more if you are still returning the same resource, in your example it is `/articles'.

But using a query parameter with a boolean type or just a parameter without any value is not a good practice. Because this approach is not extensible.

For example, if you want to add a filter based on other criteria (e.g. "deleted" or "draft", or "not completed"), you need to add other query parameters with the boolean type, because it will be difficult to change the API that is being used right now. And that might look like this:

```
/articles?withUnpublished&withDeleted&withUncompleted
```

It looks kind of weird.

Instead, you can create a filter as a query parameter, which will be whatever you want. And it will make your API more extensible.

For example:

```
/articles?status=UNPUBLISHED
```

And if you want to extend the filter you just need to support another status or multiple statuses.

```
/articles?status=DRAFT,DELETED
```

Of course, the access verification method becomes more complicated, but the API becomes more flexible. It might make sense after all.

Comment: I see, so i think we should only separate the endpoints only if the structure of the request body & the response body is totally different right? Or if there is have two different use case for that service

Comment: If one URL can return different data structures, for example, depends on the request parameter, this significantly complicates the API design, and the same thing if one URL can handle different data structures. @AzvyaErstevan

Comment: If you want to have a separate hidden protected URL for special users, you can fork it from the entry point. For example [the entry point](https://restful-api-design.readthedocs.io/en/latest/urls.html) will be `/api`. In this case, `/api/articles` is a public API, but `/api/private/articles` or `/api/admin/articles` is a private URL accessible only to users with access. And under `/api/private/...`, you can create any other URLs this way. @AzvyaErstevan

Answer (score 0):

As far as REST is concerned, these:

```
/articles
/articles?withUnpublished
```

are already two different *resources*, so there's no general purpose reason to separate them further.

Your specific implementation might care, and of course you might also want to consider the needs of humans who document the code, or review the access logs, and so on.

---

> Why are these two different resources? There is only one resource that has filtering

Two different resource identifiers means two different resources.  The fact that they happen to have a common [path](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-3.3) is not significant.

Said another way, the [query](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-3.4) is part of the resource identifier.

Here's a simpler example:

```
/example?a=1
/example?a=2
```

These URI identify two different resources, even though the differ by only a single character and could easily be generated/parsed using the same URI template.

See also [RFC 3986](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-3.4)

> The query component contains non-hierarchical data that, along with
> data in the path component (Section 3.3), serves to identify a
> resource within the scope of the URI's scheme and naming authority

Comment: Why are these two different resources? There is only one resource that has filtering.

Comment: I think the query is not part of the resource identification, the resource is identified by a path segment. The query defines a selection of data related to the resource. That means that `/articles?a=1` and `/articles?a=2` return different data (different collections) of the same resource.